# Application Always Downloading

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I notice sometimes an app (in this case Dropbox) is always downloading when I go into Market > Downloads. I even uninstalled it. So it doesn't appear in my application list but it still says Downloading in the Market. The progress bar is empty.

I couldn't find anything on the web. Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had trouble downloading the latest update. What I did was from the list of applications in the Market, I did a long press and **Cancel download**. After that I was able to select it and download it successfully.

Comment: That did it. I think I had tried cancelling the download, either after a short press or via the menu, but it kept starting up again (without finishing). Thanks!