# Lollipop + Google Play - small application installs take 10 or more minutes?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, 5.0-lollipop, installation, samsung-galaxy-s-5

The specs:

- Samsung Galaxy S5
- Android 5.0 Lollipop (new device, came with it)

Installing small applications in Google Play Store take 3-15 minutes, Spotify has been "installing" for over an hour. It's not the Wifi speed, because speedtest on the device showed 20-30mbit/s download, and my other Android 4 device installs the same application within a few seconds.

Any ideas? Are Google Play application installs fast on your Android 5 devices?

I tried removing the SD card, didn't help.

Comment: Andrew it might be because you have low internal/phone memory..apps are not directly installed onto SD card..so that's irrelevant and won't help.

Comment: There's gigabytes of internal memory, and 500mb+ free RAM, so that's not it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to solve it, got the idea from here: [Application stuck in "Installing..." stage in Market](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1975/application-stuck-in-installing-stage-in-market).

I went to Settings > Applications > Manage Applications.

1. Force stop the *Google Play Store* application
2. Uninstall updates for the *Google Play Store* application

It warned me that Google Play Store would be restored to its original state, I accepted.

After this, I launched Google Play Store and installing applications was lightning fast. :)