# How to revive crashing market app?

Tags: google-play-store, crashes

My Android 2.1 tablet crashed while the marked app was installing some apps. If I open the marked app now, it always shows that two apps are installing right now, and crashes immediately. Any ideas on how to fix that problem? I already removed the apps the market thinks it is installing, but that did not help. :-/

Comment: See also http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1518/2387 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I generally deal with truculent apps is by following each of these steps until it starts working again.

1. Force stop
2. Clear cache
3. Clear app data
4. Restart the device
5. Uninstall/reinstall (this may be tricky with the Market app)

Comment: Yep, going to `Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications` and doing steps 1 and 3 for the Market should be enough.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't - I cleared the cache and data for both Market and Market-Update, and it still thinks it is installing the apps. It did help a little, though - marked does not crash anymore, so I can at least install other apps again. 8-)

Comment: Try doing a long-press on those "installing" records and see if it gives you an option to cancel.

Comment: The problem disappeared when I was installing an Upgrade to Android 2.2 . I believe I tried the long press with no result, but I am not sure anymore.