# what is Market, on an Android device?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

In looking up an issue I'm having, I came across 2 questions and associated answers that talked about "Market" (for example, [Application Always Downloading](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1518/application-always-downloading)).

I've never heard of this app, and couldn't find anything on my phone that even resembled it. I also couldn't find it in Google Play or Google's search engine, and couldn't really find anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

Something about how it was talked about on the aforementioned questions/answers made it seem a lot like Google Play. [Turns out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play), it basically is.

Comment: Heh...I thought this answer was a bit rude...then I made it O_o Hope this makes someone laugh